# ReactJS useState not updating momentJS prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, use-effect

I am coding a CRM app and there's a asnyc function for `gettingTrackers` and it working well. There's another function called `calculateStartTime` and this function suppose to calculate `momentJS` variable and set it but this is not updating.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function gettingTrackers() {
      await getTrackers(null, null);
    }

    gettingTrackers();
    calculateStartTime();
}, []);


const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

const calculateStartTime = () => {
const dateOfMay = moment("2020-05-01");
const now = moment();

let timeTheStart = null;
let timeTheEnd = null;

if (now.add(-32, "d").diff(dateOfMay) <= 0) {
   timeTheStart = dateOfMay.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
   timeTheEnd = moment().add(-2, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
} else {
   timeTheStart = moment().add(-32, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
   timeTheEnd = moment().add(-2, "d").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
}

console.log("calculating...")
console.log("start time > ", timeTheStart)
console.log("end time > ", timeTheEnd);


setStartTime(moment(timeTheStart).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
setEndTime(moment(timeTheEnd).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

// these 2 logs prints initial value, not updated value.
console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime)
}
```

The problem is that I have to send `startTime` and `endTime` to another ReactJS component, and it sends first initial today value every time. When I call `calculateStartTime` it logs

```
calculating...
start time >  2020-06-07
end time >  2020-07-07
```

But when I click to button for another component, I print these variables and its output;

```
2020-07-09
2020-07-09
```

as initial values. I log them with using `startTime` and `endTime` as I described in `useState`

What I am missing on this problem? Is there any memory-leak to not-working?

Edit:

```
const goToResultButton = (event, data) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    console.log("start time > ", startTime)
    console.log("end time  > ", endTime)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below code block, you are setting the state and immediately you are trying to access the updated value, but state updates done in async fashion. You will get the latest value in the next re-render.

```js
    ...
    setStartTime(moment(timeTheStart).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
    setEndTime(moment(timeTheEnd).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

    // these 2 logs prints initial value, not updated value.
    console.log(startTime);
    console.log(endTime)
   ...
```

You can use a `useEffect` to log or do something with latest values of startTime and endTime.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("startTime", startTime);
  console.log("endTime", endTime);
}, [startTime, endTime]);
```

Comment: thanks for answer @gdh, `calculateStartTime()` is changing `startTime` and `endTime` and when these changes, `useEffect` called again, and there's a cycle. What do you suggest to solve it? Is there any efficient way to solve it besides that stores 2 another state variable?

Comment: yes, that's how `useEffect` works .... if you want to catch the changes on startTime & endTime then you can use the useEffect by providing the dependecy . When startTime & endTime changes , the useEffect executes....there is no prob with it ... it is meant to be like that...